# Поддомен .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сайт site.ru, хотелось бы сделать через .htaccess что бы был поддомен. и работал так  "t.site.ru/name" => "site.ru/tg.php?un=name"

Много вариантов уже попробовал

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^t.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.ru/tg.php?un=$1 [R=301,L]
```

заходит правильно, но в адресной строке:  http://site.ru/tg.php?un= 
как сделать что бы в адресе оставалось t.site.ru ?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить [R=301,L] на [L,QSA]

Comment: Давид, не помогло(